# running DHTMLX APIs without a browser

Tags: backend, dhtmlx

We are using DHTMLX to let users view and edit gantt. We need to be able to support changes that are triggered by a CRON job. These changes need to update the end-dates of several tasks (without involvement of a user / browser). Is there a way to call DHTMLX APIs on the backend?

TNX

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the 7.0 version, it is possible to run Gantt on the server-side:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/whatsnew.html#x4465x70x4466x
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__using_gantt_on_server.html